# What is the meaning of test runner? What is the meaning of test runner in layman terms?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

What is the meaning of test runner? Protractor is a test runner. What is the meaning of test runner in layman terms?

Comment: It is as simple as it name suggest, running test using what test framework/tool you have selected(Protractor, Selenium or etc). General idea is, when you create your test scripts and compile it, these tool will execute these test and writes results based on your setup.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, it's interesting to understand [the difference between a framework and a library](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library-bd133054023f/):

In a nutshell, a library is a piece of code that your application code calls:
Here you are calling the Selenium **library** functions:
WebDriver().get("duckduckgo.com");

On the other hand, a framework is a code **that calls your application code**:

```
@Test
fun myTest():
...
```

In the example above, the code you wrote will be called by a framework, e.g. JUnit. The [Callback Pattern](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781783287314/1/ch01lvl1sec10/the-callback-pattern) is a perfect example of this.

So, test runners are applications that will run your tests that are organized in a certain way:

- Annotated with @Test;
- Inside files the end with *test.js*
- etc...

They are frameworks. **Their workflow** is what determines what will happen, they have execution control.

Protractor, Selenium, and alike (mostly) are libraries. Your application code will call them. Your code workflow is what determines what will happen, you have execution control.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome Ramya. If you found the answer satisfactory, could you mark it as Accepted? It really motivate contributors.

Comment: How to mark as accepted? Very sorry to have asked this question. I am very new to this.

Comment: If you are log in the site, there is a check sign besides up and down arrows on the left of the answer text. You can click on it.